# template function with same return type and same argument

Tags: templates, sfinae

I am trying to create a template function as below

```
template<typename T>
using IsUnfoldedWire = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<T, UnfoldedWire>::value>;
template<typename T>
using IsUnfoldedInst = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<T, UnfoldedInstance>::value>;

template<typename T, typename = IsUnfoldedWire<T>>
unsigned getUnfoldedIndex() const { return _unfoldedWireIndex; }

template<typename T, typename = IsUnfoldedInstance<T>>
unsigned getUnfoldedIndex() const { return _unfoldedInstIndex; }
```

But the compiler is complaining the 2 functions cannot be overloaded. Can you suggest how can I use the
template function here?

Answer (score 0):

In C++17, you can use [constexpr if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if)
and one function will make it.

```cpp
template<typename T>
unsigned getUnfoldedIndex() const
{
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, UnfoldedWire>)
        return _unfoldedWireIndex;
    else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, UnfoldedInstance>)
        return _unfoldedInstIndex;
    else
        static_assert(false, "invalid type");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

using `typename = std::enable_if_t<(some conditions)>`'s style SFINAE will has same function significants (sometimes we prefer or not). so in this case, you can use `std::enable_if_t<(some conditions), int> = 0`'s style:

```cpp
template<typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<T, UnfoldedWire>::value, int> = 0>
unsigned getUnfoldedIndex() const { return _unfoldedWireIndex; }

template<typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<T, UnfoldedInstance>::value, int> = 0>
unsigned getUnfoldedIndex() const { return _unfoldedInstIndex; }
```